# Grails - Register ServletContextListener or initialize via BootStrap.groovy

Tags: grails, servlets

I just rethought my implementation of the Logback initialization within my Grails project, where it is realized through a `ServletContextListener` which provides the `ServletContext` once fired and triggers the whole Logback initialization thing.

In `BootStrap.groovy` I've already got a `ServletContext` object within the `init` closure, so why not trigger the Logback initialization from this closure?

A huge benefit (for me) by using the BootStrap initialization is, that I don't have to run `grails install-templates` and register the Listener within the `web.xml` file... 
**Are there any drawbacks if I don't register a `ServletContextListener` and instead take the `ServletContext` from `BootStrap.groovy`?**

I'd love to read your thoughts on this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've seen from a simple test, it surely takes effect on startup in so far, as the Logback initialization is invoked way earlier in the startup process when registering a `ServletContextListener` in the `web.xml` file instead of invoke the method from the `BootStrap.groovy` file ...

As far as I know, the `JVM` would compile all `Java` classes first, so that the underlying Spring Framework will fire quicker than the `Groovy` files on top of it.

**Conclusion:**
Don't invoke methods from `BootStrap.groovy` if you need them early on startup, otherwise there are no drawbacks (at least I haven't seen any, so far)....